How can I simulate that I'm pressing two keys at the same time? (win32gui)
I'm trying to simulate that I'm pressing two keys at the same time in a program that is not focused, that is not active, that is minimized.
I tried running the following code snippet:
def send_message_to(message, partial_title="Title"):
    hwnd = find_window(partial_title)
    if hwnd:
        window_placement = win32gui.GetWindowPlacement(hwnd)
        if window_placement[1] == win32con.SW_SHOWMINIMIZED:
            win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_RESTORE)
        if window_placement[1] != win32con.SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED:
            win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
        for char in message:
            win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_CHAR, ord(char), 0)

        # Pressionar Shift e Enter ao mesmo tempo
        win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_SHIFT, 0)
        win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_RETURN, 0)
        win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, win32con.VK_SHIFT, 0)
        win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, win32con.VK_RETURN, 0)

    else:
        print("Not found,")

But it only executes one command at a time.
